# magento keeps redirecting to my production website and not my staging website

Tags: database, configuration, local.xml, htaccess

I uploaded all the files from my production website to my staging website which is hosted on a server.

I then uploaded my entire production DB to my staging server. Additionally, I changed the local xml to reflect the new connection strings.

I changed the secure and unsecure urls in the core_config_data table to reflect my staging website URL.

It's still redirecting to my main website. My staging website is a subdomain, I've never ran into this problem before. Does it have anything to do with it being a subdomain?

stage.mywebsite.com

mywebsite.com

Could it be something in my htaccess file or other config files?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '23181' for key 'PRIMARY'

Trace:
#0 /home/stage555/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /home/stage555/public_html/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /home/stage555/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /home/stage555/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `lo...', Array)
#4 /home/stage555/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `lo...', Array)
#5 /home/stage555/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(576): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `lo...', Array)
#6 /home/stage555/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Log/Model/Resource/Visitor.php(174): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->insert('log_visitor_inf...', Array)
#7 /home/stage555/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Log/Model/Resource/Visitor.php(108): Mage_Log_Model_Resource_Visitor->_saveVisitorInfo(Object(Mage_Log_Model_Visitor))
#8 /home/stage555/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(463): Mage_Log_Model_Resource_Visitor->_afterSave(Object(Mage_Log_Model_Visitor))
#9 /home/stage555/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(318): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->save(Object(Mage_Log_Model_Visitor))
#10 /home/stage555/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Log/Model/Visitor.php(168): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->save()
#11 /home/stage555/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1338): Mage_Log_Model_Visitor->initByRequest(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#12 /home/stage555/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1317): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Mage_Log_Model_Visitor), 'initByRequest', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#13 /home/stage555/public_html/app/Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array)
#14 /home/stage555/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(527): Mage::dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array)
#15 /home/stage555/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Front/Action.php(64): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->preDispatch()
#16 /home/stage555/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(407): Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action->preDispatch()
#17 /home/stage555/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#18 /home/stage555/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#19 /home/stage555/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#20 /home/stage555/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#21 /home/stage555/public_html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#22 {main}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check inside your `core_config_data` table in your database.  There is are values called:

```
web/unsecure/base_url
web/secure/base_url
```

Make sure those are pointing to the right domain.

Flush your session storage and var/cache, as it holds url information.

Also, try turning off your auto-redirect to base url setting in System->Configuration->Web->Url Options.

Comment: I already changed those and i stated that in the above. Thank you for the response.

Comment: updated to reflect additional options to try.

Comment: I can't get into admin because it redirects me to the live website, so is there another way to get to the URL options in system configuartion > web > url options?

Comment: Go into the database and update the core_config_data table.  The path is web/url/redirect_to_base.  Set this value to 0.

Comment: i can't flush session storage either because i can't access admin panel because it redirects. I did clear my cache through my ftp my visting the var > cache folder and deleting everything.

Comment: You can also flush the session storage in var/session.

Comment: Ok, i set it to 0 and i'm clearing the cache again. So directly in my ftp can i just go into the session folder and delete everything?

Comment: Go into var/session and delete everything out of there.  There should be a number of files in that folder.

Comment: I think were getting somewhere... i just received a db error.. i'll post it above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21050/discussion-between-ryan-street-and-rad).

Comment: After i truncated the tables it worked. Well, i followed all your other advice too about clearing the session and cache and redirect base to 0. Thank you very much @Ryan Street.

Comment: `web/unsecure/base_link_url` in `core_config_data` needs to change as well!! I spent a good deal of time before I realized changing this fixes the re-directing issue.

Answer (score 0):

No it's not `.htaccess`
When I get that kind of weirdness I simply rename `app/ect/local.xml` to `local_old.xml` and rerun first part of installation. Usually it sorts that kind problem :)

Comment: rerun the first part of the installation as to re-upload all the files through ftp? that will take a long time.

Answer (score 0):

No just Rename local.xml
Go to your site url and you Will see magento setup.
Enter all details again and you don't need to install anything new local.xml will be created with correct details of your database and url 
Happy end!